# Conditional function test for presence of file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to check the size of a file within a rule, but only if the file is present. check_size is a custom function. In the below make doesn't even get around to calling check_size:

```
    $(if $(test -f $(file)),\
        @$(call check_size,$(shell stat -f%z $(file),$(size)))
```

I don't see what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Vj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no make function `test`, so `$(test -f $(file))` causes make to try to expand a make variable named `test -f $(file)`, which obviously doesn't exist, so it expands to the empty string.

Because of that, the if-condition is always false (in make `if` functions and other conditions, the empty string is false and a non-empty string is true) and the then-clause is not expanded.

It's actually somewhat tricky to use make functions like this inside a recipe and have them do what you want, and also I can't really figure out what your `call` does here: why are you passing `$(file),$(size)` to the `stat` program in the shell??  But since there is no info on what `check_size` does we'll have to assume it's necessary.

In that case you'll have to use real make functions; the one you want to use to test if a file exists is `wildcard` which will expand to the name of the file if it exists or the empty string if not... so:

```
$(if $(wildcard $(file)), \
    @$(call check_size,$(shell stat -f%z $(file),$(size)))
```